# How to JDBC return string key'ed map

Tags: jdbc, clojure

How can I set `jdbc`to return the maps with `string` keys?

```clj
(require '[clojure.java.jdbc :as j])

(j/query
  database
  ["SELECT * FROM User WHERE Name = ?" "Daniel"]) => ({:name "Daniel", :id 3})
```

How you might have noticed, the return is mapped with lowercase keys.

Is there a way to return exactly the name of the fields?
(as `string`, preferently)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`clojure.java.jdbc/query`](http://clojure.github.io/java.jdbc/#clojure.java.jdbc/query) supports `:identifiers` options which should be a function that will be applied to the column name before converting it to a keyword.

If you would like to preserve the original case you can just pass `identity` function.

I am afraid there is no option to return strings instead of keywords as column identifiers.